# Portlet Deployment issue on Liferay 7

Tags: javascript, java, json, liferay, liferay-7

I am new to Liferay. I am currently doing a lab exercise on the Liferay guestbook. I followed the instructions given and when run my tomcat server, I received this error on my console. Does anyone know what error it is?

```
02:59:07,818 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-2][JSONWebServiceServiceAction:97] Access denied to com.liferay.portal.workflow.kaleo.service.KaleoDefinitionService#getKaleoDefinitions
```

> https://dev.liferay.com/en/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/writing-your-first-liferay-application

Comment: The guestbook exercise is a pretty common exercise in Liferay and it is used to show features in several contexts. it is king of a hello word. And I am saying that because people will not know exactly what you are doing. Please add extra information, so we can help you. Normally, there are links to the dev manual you can also provide.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens occurs when we are trying to access Liferay remote web service without authentication,in this case,being a tutorial,trying to access without logging in to Portal